# How to get current user role name in Sitecore using Powershell

Tags: powershell-extensions

How can I read the role name of current logged-in user in `Sitecore PowerShell` Module?

Comment: A note about the available commands: they work with the built-in Aspnet Membership. It has not directly integration with security information revealed through Identity Server.

Answer (score 4):

You can try below command -

```
Get-User -Current
```

You can try some options as well -

```
Get-User [-Identity] <AccountIdentity> [-Authenticated]
Get-User -Filter <String> [-Authenticated] [-ResultPageSize <Int32>]
```

Docs for references - https://doc.sitecorepowershell.com/appendix/security/get-user
https://munirhassan.com/2021/10/17/powershell-scrips-to-get-sitecore-user-information/

Answer (score 3):

To get all roles which are directly assigned to a Sitecore user, you can use the following Sitecore Powershell Extensions script

```
$user = Get-User "sitecore\USERNAME"
$roles = $user.Roles
$roles
```